# How can we smell odor direction if we breathe through one nostril at a time?

Tags: physiology, olfaction

It's known that humans [breathe mostly through one nostril at a time](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/21216/why-do-i-only-breathe-out-of-one-nostril). How can we then perceive the direction the smell is coming from? Some articles [claim similarity between olfactory and auditory directional perception](https://www.physiology.org/doi/abs/10.1152/jappl.1964.19.3.369):

> The direction of a sound source can be determined binaurally by using
>   the time difference and the loudness difference of the sound waves
>   arriving at the two ears. Similarly, the direction of an olfactory
>   source can be determined by using the time difference and the
>   difference in sensation magnitude of the olfactory stimuli between the
>   two nostrils as the air surrounding the odorous object is inhaled.
>   Time differences of the order of 0.1 msec can be recognized—a value
>   similar to that found in hearing.

However, that explanation runs afoul of breathing mostly through only one nostril at a time because at least the `difference in sensation magnitude of the olfactory stimuli` should depend heavily on which nostril is 85% shut and which one is wide open.

Comment: HI Michael. I think your question can be solved by re-reading the source you interpreted to mean humans only "use" one nostril at a time.

Comment: @DeNovo, if you barely breeze through the 85% closed nostril you are unlikely to smell through it with the same intensity as through the open one. That makes it unlikely that you can use at least `the difference in sensation magnitude of the olfactory stimuli between the two nostrils as the air surrounding the odorous object is inhaled` part of the suggested mechanism of directional olfactory sense.

Comment: I believe both the low flow and high flow nostril are used to detect smells in a given cycle. I think your question could be improved by changing "use one nostril at a time" to "breathe from one nostril at a time", since you're saying "Its known..." It is **not** known that humans only detect smells from one nostril at a time.

Comment: Good edit, and I think this is a very interesting question. I just edited myself to change breeze to "breathe", which I think is what you meant. Feel free to roll back if i misunderstood. I don't have electronic access to the physiology study from the 60s you referenced, but I am very curious as to whether they took this into consideration.

Comment: my guess is that it requires detecting differences in concentration by turning your head.

Comment: A more recent (and complete) article: https://www.nature.com/articles/srep05796